# North-East facing room - Gets too hot - Suggestions required to keep my room livable

Tags: insulation, cooling, heat

I am in the hottest part of Southern California.
My room is North-East facing and in summer when it is usually 115 F outside, my room gets really unlivable - live it is 95 F inside the room despite running a fan and keeping the door open. There's only one window which I cover and curtain during summer and just use the electric lights.

What are some effective ways to reduce heat gain through an outside wall in a room that faces northeast in a hot climate, despite having installed an attic fan and extra roof insulation?

Split AC is not an option as it requires a ton of expense and labor.

Comment: How about a window AC unit  when it's 115 out and you have no AC, you're lucky it's only 95 in the room. the fan will only move the air, not cool it down.

Comment: What color is the roof? That's where it's coming from, it's **solar gain** from the roof.  South and west walls also have a problem with this.  North and east walls don't.  However if ambient air in the shade is 115F your only option is mechanical A/C. Get a window unit (as little as $99) or a 2-hose portable. [1-hose portables are bad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-mBeYC2KGc) and take way too much power due to their dumb design.  If that's not an option then during those times, go out and do stuff elsewhere.

Comment: In summer, depending on the latitude, the sun will shine on east-facing walls and even on north-facing walls at certain times of day. Hanging a sun shade outside from the edge of the roof may help cut the warming.

Comment: What kind of insulation—reflective?

Comment: color of roof - terracota / lightbrown
window a/c - I have to break the wall or window right? wouldn't that be a huge affair?
No reflective thing there. It is a 35 year old house we moved just before covid. What is this reflective thing, some sort of paint? We have an HOA which does not allow us to change the color though.

Comment: I like the sunshade hanging thing, was thinking of that too. Any suggestions and any examples? We have quite a bit of wind here and I am not sure if the patio shade might help in any way. I have to install a long pole (at least 2 poles and as high as Ground + 1) the opp side of the wall to hang a sail shade.